# run command before/while systemd-logind

Tags: systemd, init, logind

I'd like to run a command, i.e. `archhey3` just before or rather while logind is prompting for username and password at the virtual console.
Can someone point me in the right direction? checked the arch-wiki pages of `init` and `systemd` already.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_boot_process#Message_of_the_day

Comment: @jasonwryan ok it's getty, thanks! any idea how i can achieve something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683357/ubuntu-run-command-on-start-up-with-sudo on arch? where is the exec getty command / what executes getty on arch?

Comment: Err, no, it is motd. And you want a service file for the SO thing.

Comment: `logind` is not what prompts for usernames and passwords.  That is `login`, a different program and a different service.